# React Native debugger cannot import bundle script?

Tags: android, debugging, reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I've just tried setting up the react native debugger in WebStorm 2016.3 on my Windows machine. I followed the setup exactly from their [blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/10/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-6512/).

However, when I enable remote debugging from my Android simulator, the WebStorm console throws this error:

```
[intellij] [Warning] Couldn't import script at <http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false>.   
Debugging won't work: Try reloading the JS from inside the app, or Reconnect the debugger: Cannot GET /json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2......
```

I have no issues if I were connecting to Chrome's devtools as debugger, but it will really be nice to have a debugger within an IDE.

What does this error mean and how can I get the react native debugger in WebStorm to work?

Comment: Did you figure it out ? I'm having the same problem with PhpStorm

Comment: I still haven't figured this out. :(

Comment: I restarted my computer and it worked afterwards. Kinda weird.

Comment: Sadly, restarting my computer doesn't work for me. Have you made any changes or configurations before you restart?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I turned off the remote debugger using the react-native in-app dev menu. That's probably what fixed it though.

Answer (score 1):

I use node 7.3.0 before and I had the same problem with WebStorm.
Now, I install node 6.9.3 insted of node 7.3.0,and the problem had been sovled.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm using node 6.9.3 at the moment and I'm still stuck with this problem.